# How to execute parameterized select query on .mdf database and display a column value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, parameterized-query, select-query

I have a SQL Server database file `MsUser.mdf` with a table `MsAccount` that has 5 columns:

```
userID   accountID   accountName   accountBalance   imageLocation
```

I need to find the `accountBalance` where `accountID = combobox` that being selected, and show it in `labelBalance._text`. `AccountBalance` is `decimal`, `accountID` is `varchar(10)`.

I wrote the code at comboBox event selected index.
Thanks for helping.

```
      private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          string selected = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();//typ0000001-cake
          int position = selected.IndexOf("-");
          string accountID = selected.Substring(0,position);//typ0000001
          SqlDataAdapter sdaUserID = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(accountBalance),accountBalance From MsAccount where accountID='" +accountID+"'", cn);
          DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
          sdaUserID.Fill(dt1);
          lblBalance.text = dt1.Rows[0][1].ToString();

      }
```

Comment: You have to include your code (both SQL statement and C#) and specify the problem part. Also, it looks like you are trying to select a row based on condition accountID= combobox.text and display a value in a column accountBalance (I have edited your question correspondingly). Thanks and regards,

Comment: @Alex Bell Thanks for your guidance, i'll remember that rules. and thanks for everyone that have help me to correct my post.
about someone that complain my grammar, i'm so sorry, i'm not that good at english. that's not my native language, but i still improve my english language.

Comment: You are welcome @Eka Soedono! I've posted an answer showing some performance optimization. In case you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it accepted. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad you got your code working. In general, it would be better to create a parameterized query, but if security is not a major concern, then just a plain select SQL string will do the job (as in your case).

Couple words regarding some performance optimization: I would recommend to use `String.Concat(string1, string2)` instead of `string1+string2` approach, thus it would be better to modify the line from your code as shown below:

```
SqlDataAdapter sdaUserID = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Concat ("Select Count(accountBalance),accountBalance From MsAccount where accountID='",accountID, "'"), cn);
```

Best regards,

Comment: i've change SDA as you recommended. at `sdaUserID.Fill(dt1);` there an eror when i click and open the form, it says **sqlException was unhandled by user code : Column 'MsAccount.accountBalance' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.** thanks for helping me.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,